# Cleaning python data frames, various items in one column to either male or female

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame file where respondents have identified their gender in numerous ways, for example for female, instances include: ‘female’, ‘F’, ‘f’ and ‘Female’ and others.
I need to change all the instances in the column "Gender" to reflect either ‘Male’ or 'Female' in order to construct a pie chart.

I tried numerous methods to cleanse the data, including:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my csv file.csv')

misspellings = ['f', 'woman', 'femail', 'cis-female/femme', 'female (cis)', 'cis female', 'femake']
for s in misspellings:
    df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].replace(s, 'female')
```

I just can't get it to update correctly.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

This would work:

```
df['Gender'].replace(mispellings, 'female')
```